# Does Python have a package manager

Tags: python

I had used Node JS and now learning Python.
Does python have some website and GitHub repos for something like NPM/Yarn of Node JS?

Comment: NPM and Yarn are called package managers. I've edited the title.

Comment: [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)).

Answer (score 1):

NPM and Yarn are **package managers for NodeJS**, assuming you know what they are and what they do. There is a widely used package manager for Python language as well. It is called pip, its documentation is available [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/). The Github link is https://github.com/pypa/pip.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. It is called **`pip`** (***p**ackage **i**nstaller for **p**ython*) - [Docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/)

> pip is the package installer for Python. You can use it to install packages from the Python Package Index and other indexes.